# oracle analytical function for time period

Tags: oracle, function, analytical

I'm trying to find out a way with Oracle(11g) analytical function to get a time period in status data.
My data are like this:

```css
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>Date</th> 
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Service A</td>
    <td>01.01.2018 08:00</td>
    <td>OK</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Service A</td>
    <td>01.01.2018 08:05</td>
    <td>OK</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Service A</td>
    <td>01.01.2018 08:10</td>
    <td>WARNING</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Service A</td>
    <td>01.01.2018 08:15</td>
    <td>WARNING</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Service A</td>
    <td>01.01.2018 08:20:00</td>
    <td>WARNING</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Service A</td>
    <td>01.01.2018 08:25:00</td>
    <td>WARNING</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Service A</td>
    <td>01.01.2018 08:30:00</td>
    <td>OK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Service A</td>
    <td>01.01.2018 08:35:00</td>
    <td>OK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I habe a lot of services, more different status and finaly a lot of data.
**My question is how I get in a smart anlalytical way a result like this:**

```
Service,   Start_date,       End_date,        Status
Service A, 01.01.2018 08:00, 01.01.2018 08:05,OK
Service A, 01.01.2018 08:10, 01.01.2018 08:25,WARNING
Service A, 01.01.2018 08:30, 01.01.2018 08:35,OK
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/082d93/12)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (Service varchar2(9), Date_t DATE, Status varchar2(7))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO yourtable (Service, Date_t, Status)
         VALUES ('Service A', TIMESTAMP  '2018-01-01 08:00:00', 'OK')
    INTO yourtable (Service, Date_t, Status)
         VALUES ('Service A', TIMESTAMP  '2018-01-01 08:05:00', 'OK')
    INTO yourtable (Service, Date_t, Status)
         VALUES ('Service A', TIMESTAMP  '2018-01-01 08:10:00', 'WARNING')
    INTO yourtable (Service, Date_t, Status)
         VALUES ('Service A', TIMESTAMP  '2018-01-01 08:15:00', 'WARNING')
    INTO yourtable (Service, Date_t, Status)
         VALUES ('Service A', TIMESTAMP  '2018-01-01 08:20:00', 'WARNING')
    INTO yourtable (Service, Date_t, Status)
         VALUES ('Service A', TIMESTAMP  '2018-01-01 08:25:00', 'WARNING')
    INTO yourtable (Service, Date_t, Status)
         VALUES ('Service A', TIMESTAMP  '2018-01-01 08:30:00', 'OK')
    INTO yourtable (Service, Date_t, Status)
         VALUES ('Service A', TIMESTAMP  '2018-01-01 08:35:00', 'OK')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
 SELECT service,
       MIN (date_t) start_date,
       MAX(date_t)  end_date,
       MAX(status) Status
FROM   (SELECT service,
               date_t,
               status,
               row_number()
                 over (
                   ORDER BY date_t ) - row_number()
                                         over (
                                           PARTITION BY service, status
                                           ORDER BY date_t ) stat_change
        FROM   yourtable)
GROUP  BY service,
          stat_change
ORDER  BY start_date,
          end_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/082d93/12/0)**:

```
|   SERVICE |           START_DATE |             END_DATE |  STATUS |
|-----------|----------------------|----------------------|---------|
| Service A | 2018-01-01T08:00:00Z | 2018-01-01T08:05:00Z |      OK |
| Service A | 2018-01-01T08:10:00Z | 2018-01-01T08:25:00Z | WARNING |
| Service A | 2018-01-01T08:30:00Z | 2018-01-01T08:35:00Z |      OK |
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik Nayak
I was close, but I could not see this easy step for grouping in status_change.
Many thanks